# IE8 only raises mouse click over text in table cell

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

I have an issue that arises in IE8, but doesn’t occur in IE7 or in IE8 compatibility mode. In IE8 I can only raise a mouse click event when the mouse is over text in a table cell. If the mouse is over a blank area in the same cell, the mouse click event isn’t raised. The tables are dynamically generated. The browser is running in quirks mode.

The code works fine in all browsers. I was just wondering if you know of something with IE8 that would cause it to recognize the mouse click only when positioned over text in the cell and not the entire table cell.  The table is fixed layout with specified width for each column.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this is because the bacakground of the cell is transparent.
Try setting the background of the cell to a color.
Once I did, I got the clicks as expected...